# hadoop - How long can we check the status upon completion of mapreduce job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have 3 mapreduce jobs to be executed in parallel, thus, i've done something like this

```
Job[] job = new Job[3];
.
.
.
job[0].submit();
job[1].submit();
job[2].submit();
```

So to check if all jobs are successful, i put some polling on the 3 jobs.

```
boolean isAllFinished = false;
while(!isAllFinished) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        log.debug("job["+i+"].isComplete() >> " + job[i].isComplete());
        isAllFinished = isAllFinished & job[i].isComplete();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Though, this yield positively, it failed on random occasions where I would have these kind of error/log:

```
14/04/08 18:43:59 DEBUG FMS: job[0].isComplete() >> false
14/04/08 18:44:00 DEBUG FMS: job[1].isComplete() >> false
14/04/08 18:44:01 DEBUG FMS: job[2].isComplete() >> false
14/04/08 18:44:12 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
14/04/08 18:44:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/04/08 18:44:14 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/04/08 18:44:15 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

I'm thinking if there is a timeout on up to when we can check the job status via Job class. Appreciate any thoughts on this!

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop job can be configured to wait till the completion using `job.waitForCompletion(true);`

You can try code like below :

```
job[0].waitForCompletion(true);
job[1].waitForCompletion(true);
job[2].waitForCompletion(true);
```

If you want to provide timeout, then you can use `wait(timeout)` method.

```
job[0].wait(1000);
```

Comment: agree on it, however, i need to run the 3 jobs in parallel. That's why i'm looking into utilizing the isComplete() and isSuccessful() methods of Job class.

Comment: Why not start a thread for each job and then join the threads to block until they complete?